# GO language: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go

Code below works fine with hard coded JSON data however doesn't work when I read JSON data from a file. I'm getting `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock` error when using `sync.WaitGroup`.

**WORKING EXAMPLE WITH HARD-CODED JSON DATA:**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func connect(host string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("ssh", host, "uptime")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s: %q\n", host, out.String())
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Printf("%s: DONE\n", host)
}

func listener(c chan string) {
    for {
        host := <-c
        go connect(host)
    }
}

func main() {
    hosts := [2]string{"user1@111.79.154.111", "user2@111.79.190.222"}
    var c chan string = make(chan string)
    go listener(c)

    for i := 0; i < len(hosts); i++ {
        c <- hosts[i]
    }
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/go$ go run channel.go
user1@111.79.154.111: " 09:46:40 up 86 days, 18:16,  0 users,  load average: 5"
user2@111.79.190.222: " 09:46:40 up 86 days, 17:27,  1 user,  load average: 9"
user1@111.79.154.111: DONE
user2@111.79.190.222: DONE
```

**NOT WORKING - EXAMPLE WITH READING JSON DATA FILE:**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

func connect(host string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("ssh", host, "uptime")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s: %q\n", host, out.String())
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Printf("%s: DONE\n", host)
}

func listener(c chan string) {
    for {
        host := <-c
        go connect(host)
    }
}

type Content struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Ip       string `json:"ip"`
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    var source []Content
    var hosts []string
    data := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
    data.Decode(&source)

    for _, value := range source {
        hosts = append(hosts, value.Username + "@" + value.Ip)
    }

    var c chan string = make(chan string)
    go listener(c)

    for i := 0; i < len(hosts); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        c <- hosts[i]
        defer wg.Done()
    }

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/go$ go run deploy.go < hosts.txt 
user1@111.79.154.111: " 09:46:40 up 86 days, 18:16,  0 users,  load average: 5"
user2@111.79.190.222: " 09:46:40 up 86 days, 17:27,  1 user,  load average: 9"
user1@111.79.154.111 : DONE
user2@111.79.190.222: DONE
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc210000068)
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/sema.goc:199 +0x30
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc210047020)
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/sync/waitgroup.go:127 +0x14b
main.main()
    /home/user/go/deploy.go:64 +0x45a

goroutine 3 [chan receive]:
main.listener(0xc210038060)
    /home/user/go/deploy.go:28 +0x30
created by main.main
    /home/user/go/deploy.go:53 +0x30b
exit status 2
user@user-VirtualBox:~/go$
```

**HOSTS.TXT**

```
[
   {
      "username":"user1",
      "ip":"111.79.154.111"
   },
   {
      "username":"user2",
      "ip":"111.79.190.222"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Go program ends when the main function ends.**

From the [language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

Therefore, you need to wait for your goroutines to finish. The common solution for this is to use [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) object.

The simplest possible code to synchronize goroutine:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

var wg sync.WaitGroup // 1

func routine() {
    defer wg.Done() // 3
    fmt.Println("routine finished")
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(1) // 2
    go routine() // *
    wg.Wait() // 4
    fmt.Println("main finished")
}
```

And for synchronizing multiple goroutines

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

var wg sync.WaitGroup // 1

func routine(i int) {
    defer wg.Done() // 3
    fmt.Printf("routine %v finished\n", i)
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1) // 2
        go routine(i) // *
    }
    wg.Wait() // 4
    fmt.Println("main finished")
}
```

WaitGroup usage in order of execution.

1. Declaration of global variable. Making it global is the easiest way to make it visible to all functions and methods.
2. Increasing the counter. This must be done in main goroutine because there is no guarantee that newly started goroutine will execute before 4 due to memory model [guarantees](http://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_5).
3. Decreasing the counter. This must be done at the exit of goroutine. Using deferred call, we make sure that it will [be called whenever function ends](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) no matter but no matter how it ends.
4. Waiting for the counter to reach 0. This must be done in main goroutine to prevent program exit.

* The actual parameters are [evaluated before starting new gouroutine](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements). Thus it is needed to evaluate them explicitly before `wg.Add(1)` so the possibly panicking code would not leave increased counter.

Use

```
param := f(x)
wg.Add(1)
go g(param)
```

instead of

```
wg.Add(1)
go g(f(x))
```

Comment: I've been using GO since yesterday (even less than a day) so I don't really know much although I've been reading the doc. The code above is result of 1 day of study/practice. Where exactly do I put sleep? I looked into the example.

Comment: @inanzzz Look at the first answer.

Comment: I think I'm putting things in wrong places. `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

Comment: Guys I updated the post above because there is a progress at least however there is a `deadlock` this time. I moved `wg` lines arround but couldn't find the correct place.

Comment: @inanzzz Updating post is not the best think you can do. Now the answer does not make sense and is no longer usable. Yes, wg.Done() call should be inside goroutines.

Comment: For those who are interested: `defer waitGroup.Done()` goes to the bottom of `connect` function. `waitGroup.Add(1)` goes into second `for` loop of `main` function (as first line) and the `waitGroup.Wait()` goes to the bottom of the same function. `var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup` is defined globally like example shows above.

Comment: @inanzzz I added additional explanations based on your comment.

Comment: It was a 1 day "programming challenge" at work and your answer helped me out a lot. Now we use go+mina instead of cap+ruby which is a new thing for us. Thanks for the additional info too.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the very nice and detailed explanation Grzegorz Żur.
One thing that I want to point it out that typically the func that needs to be threaded wont be in `main()`, so we would have something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup    // VERY IMP to declare this globally, other wise one   //would hit "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

func doSomething(arg1 arg1Type) {
     // cured cancer
}

func main() {
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    randTime := r.Intn(10)
    wg.Add(1)    
    go doSomething(randTime)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Waiting for all threads to finish")
}
```

The thing that I want to point it out is that global declaration of `wg` is very crucial for all threads to finish before `main()`

Comment: Not necessarily. You just need to make sure you are passing around a pointer so you do not get copies... `wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}` with functions: `func goDo(..., wg *sync.WaitGroup)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

/*
  Simulation for sending messages from threads for processing,
  and getting a response (processing result) to the thread
*/
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type (
    TChans []chan TMsgRec

    TMsgRec struct {
        name string //channel name
        rid  int    //-1 or  index of response channel in TChans
        msg  string // message
        note string // comment
    }

    TThRec struct { // for thread
        name string
        rid  int          // index of response channel in TChans (or -1)
        job  chan TMsgRec // chanel for send message to Receiver
        resp chan TMsgRec // response channel back to thread
    }
)

func main() {

    index := -1
    Chans := make(TChans, 100)
    index = NewChanIndex(&Chans)
    Job := Chans[index] // channel for send message from threads to Receiver

    index = NewChanIndex(&Chans) // channel index for response, for the thread "1th"
    go ping(TThRec{name: "1th", job: Job, rid: index, resp: Chans[index]})

    index = NewChanIndex(&Chans) // channel index for response, for the thread "2th"
    go ping(TThRec{name: "2th", job: Job, rid: index, resp: Chans[index]})

    Receiver(Job, Chans)
}

func Receiver(c chan TMsgRec, pChans TChans) {
    var v TMsgRec
    for {

        select {
        case v = <-c: // receive message
            {
                if v.rid > -1 {
                    //pChans[v.rid] <- TMsgRec{name: v.name, rid: -1, msg: fmt.Sprint(v.msg, ":receiver "), note: ""}
                    go worker(v, pChans[v.rid])
                }
            }
        default:
            {
                //fmt.Println("receiver")
                SleepM(2)
            }
        }
    }

}

func worker(v TMsgRec, r chan TMsgRec) {
    // simulation SQL query, or auther process
    SleepM(rand.Intn(50))
    v.msg = v.msg + ":worker"
    r <- v
}

func waitResponse(d chan TMsgRec, pTimeout int) (bool, TMsgRec) {
    var v TMsgRec
    for {
        select {
        case v = <-d:
            {
                return true, v
            }
        case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
            {
                return false, v
            }
        }
    }
}

func ping(pParam TThRec) {
    SleepM(10)
    var v TMsgRec
    ok := true
    i := 0
    for i < 500 {
        if ok {
            ok = false
            pParam.job <- TMsgRec{name: pParam.name, rid: pParam.rid, msg: fmt.Sprint(i), note: ""}
            i++
        }
        if pParam.rid > -1 {
            if !ok {
                ok, v = waitResponse(pParam.resp, 10)
                if ok {
                    fmt.Println(v.name, v.msg)
                    SleepM(1)
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(pParam.name, "response timeout")
                }

            }
        } else {
            SleepM(1)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(v.name, "-- end --")
}

func NewChanIndex(pC *TChans) int {
    for i, v := range *pC {
        if v == nil {
            (*pC)[i] = make(chan TMsgRec)
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func FreeRespChan(pC *TChans, pIndex int) {
    if (*pC)[pIndex] != nil {
        close((*pC)[pIndex]) //close channel
        (*pC)[pIndex] = nil
    }
}

func SleepM(pMilliSec int) { // sleep millisecounds
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(pMilliSec) * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

try this code snippest

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

func connect(host string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    cmd := exec.Command("ssh", host, "uptime")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s: %q\n", host, out.String())
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Printf("%s: DONE\n", host)
}

func listener(c chan string，wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        host，ok := <-c
        // check channel is closed or not
        if !ok{
            break
        }
        go connect(host)
    }

}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    hosts := [2]string{"user1@111.79.154.111", "user2@111.79.190.222"}
    var c chan string = make(chan string)
    go listener(c)

    for i := 0; i < len(hosts); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        c <- hosts[i]
    }
    close(c)
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding more context to your answer instead of simply posting a code snippet that may or may not solve the problem.