# Implement "done" pattern for concurrency running but does not work

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I try to implement in Go "Done" pattern for notify error to other channel:
Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func parse(done <-chan interface{}, data []string) <-chan string {
    stream := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        defer close(stream)
        defer fmt.Println("stream closed")

        for _, d := range data {
            m := fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", d)
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println(">>done<<")
                return
            case stream <- m:
                fmt.Printf("sent %s to stream\n", m)
            }
        }
    }()
    return stream
}

func run(migrations <-chan string) int {
    cnt := 0
    for m := range migrations {
        if m == "[a]" {
            panic("unexpected error")
        }
        fmt.Println(m)
        cnt++
    }
    return cnt
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan interface{})
    defer close(done)
    data := []string{"this", "is", "a", "test"}
    stream := parse(done, data)
    cnt := run(stream)
    fmt.Printf("total: %d messages\n", cnt)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}
```

Here is my executable link: [Play Golang URL](https://play.golang.org/p/bvQpVBLG_Qp)

But when I run, I don't see the line: "stream closed". Please explain for me why.

Comment: because it panics.

Answer (score 1):

If you run code enough, you could see `stream closed`.

Run code like the following and check the log file:

```
for I in `seq 1 10`; do go run main.go >> ./res.log 2>&1 ; done
```

[image]

I try to explain, what happened in code.

1. First of all, defer will work even panic.
2. Why we can't see "stream closed" every time? It depends on which goroutine is running, `main goroutine` or `the second(new) goroutine`.

I think the statement `defer fmt.Println("stream closed")` **in the other goroutine** cause that. When `panic` happened in **main goroutine**, there have two situation, the main goroutine still running or switch to the second goroutine.

2.1, if still main goroutine running, the process will exiting because main goroutine end, and no running time for the second goroutine to run defer statement.

2.2 if process switch to the second goroutine, the defer statement will work and "stream closed" will print out.

Answer (score 0):

The main function should look like this:

```
done := make(chan interface{})
data := []string{"this", "is", "a", "test"}
stream := parse(done, data)
close(done)
cnt := run(stream)
fmt.Printf("total: %d messages\n", cnt)
time.Sleep(time.Second)
```

The parse function sends all data before having chance to read from done channel.

This answers your question but this does not fix all the problems in the program.

Comment: even in this case. I don't see the log printed out.

Comment: so that means if we panic at main program. there is no way I can run defer in coroutine ?

Comment: When the main function ends for whatever reason, the whole program ends. Goroutines have no chance to do anything at all. They are instantly killed.

Comment: There is a way to wait for goroutines https://stackoverflow.com/a/26928625/450989

Comment: so I think in this case. we don't leak stream channel. right ?